# Drawing chart without using canvas tag in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Hi my current code already has a `createCanvas` command in it already, so i was wondering if its possible to draw my chart without using the `canvas` tag in the html file?

**Current Code:**

```
canvasContainer = select('#app');
  var c = createCanvas(1024, 600);
  c.parent('app');
```

**Chart.js uses this:**

```
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Chart.js doesn't need the canvas tag but it needs CanvasElement and its Context2d. The canvas must be added to DOM tree. Assuming that `createCanvas` is returning a Canvas Element

```
 var c = createCanvas(1024, 600);
 c.parent('app');
 var chart = new Chart(c, config);
```

Comment: i updated it with ur code and it displays this error message in console.log ```"Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'defaultCanvas0' can be reused"```

Comment: I have created a codepen https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/eYMjVmX where the canvas tag is not in html part.